# rollback saved objects whenever email send failed

Tags: django

Hi I've been wondering how to rollback a saved object on a following method when one method failed.

forms.py

```
# somewhere class forms
    def handle(self, view, request, *args, **kwargs):
           # assuming i get an object successfully.
           application = models.Application.objects.first()


           # do something in its attrs and save
           application.name = 'test'
           application.save()

           # application is fix and send via django.core.mail EmailMessage
           self.send_mail(application)

           return True
```

now when I had a good connection everything will work fine. But when it does not it will save the application but will not send the email. Resend is not an option since its a one time send supposedly. Now my idea to rollback the application and throw exception something like "Action Failed. Maybe poor connection. Please try again".

```
    try:
       application.save()
       self.send_mail(application)
    except ConnectionError?:
        # rollback ?
        raise Exception(msg) ?
```

Any help and better way to handle it? Thanks for the help and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: Are you familiar with [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/)?

Comment: Why don't you save after the email is sent ? All data will still be in the `application` object, but will be savec into database only is email is sent.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry, sadly Im no familiar at transactions though i always see transaction.atomic commonly used but I do not understand how to use it.

Comment: @Blusky thats a nice approach sir :D :D

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Much appreciated for any samples :D